# How to share the Selenium driver instance from one file to another in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, getgauge

I am currently working on a test automation suite using Selenium, NodeJS, and Gauge framework and I am having a problem with decoupling some steps into a separate file.

I am trying to decouple the step where Selenium will redirect the user to the mentioned URL to another file called `common_steps.js` as Gauge will complain that the said step is duplicated if I left it in another step implementation (which makes sense).

In the below example, the step `* Visit the application under test.` and `* Close the popup.` are used in two separate specifications.

```
scenario_test_1.spec

# Scenario Specification 1

This file follows markdown syntax. Every heading in this file denotes a scenario.
Every bulleted point denotes a step.

## Create a New Record
tags: tag1, tag2

* Visit the application under test.
* Click the Add New button
* Close the popup.
```

```
scenario_test_2.spec

# Scenario Specification 2

This file follows markdown syntax. Every heading in this file denotes a scenario. 
Every bulleted point denotes a step.

## Modify existing record
tags: tag1, tag2

* Visit the application under test.
* Click the Modify button
* Close the popup.
```

Now, when it's time to implement the step implementations of every step, since `Visit the application under test.` is already implemented once as well as `Close the popup.` step, Gauge will complain on the scenario_test_2.js that it is already defined (code below)

```
scenario_test_1.js

"use strict";

const { Builder, Browser, By, until, Key } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const assert = require("assert");
const { Options } = require("selenium-webdriver/edge");

let driver;

beforeSpec(async function () {
    const edgeOptions = new Options();
    const preferences = {
        user_experience_metrics: {
            personalization_data_consent_enabled: true,
        },
    };
    edgeOptions.setUserPreferences(preferences);
    edgeOptions.excludeSwitches(["enable-logging"]);
    edgeOptions.addArguments("InPrivate");
    driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.EDGE).setEdgeOptions(edgeOptions).build();

    await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: parseInt(process.env.test_timeout) });
    await driver.manage().window().maximize();
});

step("Visit the application under test.", async function () {
    await driver.get(process.env.BASE_URL);
});

step("Click the Add New button", async function() {
    await driver.findElement(By.id("addNewButton")).click();
});

step("Close the popup.", async function() {
    await driver.findElement(By.id("closeButton")).click();
});
```

```
scenario_test_2.js

"use strict";

const { Builder, Browser, By, until, Key } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const assert = require("assert");
const { Options } = require("selenium-webdriver/edge");

let driver;

beforeSpec(async function () {
    const edgeOptions = new Options();
    const preferences = {
        user_experience_metrics: {
            personalization_data_consent_enabled: true,
        },
    };
    edgeOptions.setUserPreferences(preferences);
    edgeOptions.excludeSwitches(["enable-logging"]);
    edgeOptions.addArguments("InPrivate");
    driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.EDGE).setEdgeOptions(edgeOptions).build();

    await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: parseInt(process.env.test_timeout) });
    await driver.manage().window().maximize();
});

step("Visit the application under test.", async function () {
    await driver.get(process.env.BASE_URL);
});

step("Click the Modify button", async function() {
    await driver.findElement(By.id("modifyButton")).click();
});

step("Close the popup.", async function() {
    await driver.findElement(By.id("closeButton")).click();
});
```

Now, the problem is that, if I decouple the `Visit the application under test.` and `Close the popup.` step, the test run will look for the variable `driver` which is undefined. If I decoupled the initialization of the driver from the `beforeSpec()` function, Gauge will spawn two browsers with both of them not doing anything because of beforeSpec() function.

I want to decouple them and pass the initialized Selenium driver in the step and have the decoupled steps use the driver instance I produced when I called the step in the specification file.

What I have done so far is to transfer the implementation of beforeSpec() to a separate function in a separate file called `common_steps.js`

```
common_functions.js

"use strict";

const { Builder, Browser } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const { Options } = require("selenium-webdriver/edge");

async function initializeDriver() {
    let driver;

    const edgeOptions = new Options();
    const preferences = {
        user_experience_metrics: {
            personalization_data_consent_enabled: true,
        },
    };
    edgeOptions.setUserPreferences(preferences);
    edgeOptions.excludeSwitches(["enable-logging"]);
    edgeOptions.addArguments("InPrivate");
    driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.EDGE).setEdgeOptions(edgeOptions).build();

    await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: parseInt(process.env.test_timeout) });
    await driver.manage().window().maximize();

    return driver;
}

exports.initializeDriver = initializeDriver;
```

```
common_steps.js

"use strict";

let driver = initializeDriver();

step("Visit the application under test.", async function () {
    await driver.get(process.env.BASE_URL);
});

step("Close the popup.", async function() {
    await driver.findElement(By.id("closeButton")).click();
});
```

and then I removed the duplicated steps in the `scenario_test_1.js` and `scenario_test_2.js` so when Gauge tries to run, it should just pick up from the corresponding file, but what I get is `driver.findElement is not a function` and upon checking, `driver` is `null`.

How do I make sure that Selenium webdriver initialized per spec is usable and available in other parts of the code?

Comment: don't know anything about this framework, but you probably want: let driver = await initializeDriver();  (Though I think in general you should stick with the framework's way of doing things rather than working around it.)

Comment: No worries, I think I found a workaround for this, but not the elegant way to do it. I did try that but to no avail.